# Decide between Storyboards at startup

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to decide between two Storyboards at startup in the app delegate.
First I removed the NSMainStoryboardFile = Main entry in the Info.plist to prevent the automatic load of a Storyboard.

Then I've tried to load the Main Storyboard from the AppDelegate but this doesn't work.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {


func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    storyboard.instantiateInitialController()
}
```

And I'm not sure why.
Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    window=UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
    var rootViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") // LoginView is your view controller name

    navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.backgroundColor=UIColor.blackColor()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work flawlessly -

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```